# Magento Media is Unsecure with SSL

Tags: magento-1.9, ssl, media, ce-1.9.2.0

I am having issues with unsecure media on my secured site. I have secured my website with a SHA-2 SSL, but whenever I go to my frontend, all of my images that I set up with `{{media url="image"}}` are pointing to unsecure images. However, if I put in the url directly with `//www.domain.com/media/wysiwyg/image`, the image pulled is secure.

Comment: Are you sure all base URLs are set to secure? As well as the `secure` as `unsecure` url

Comment: @SanderMangel I set the secure and unsecure URLs in the backend. I ended up being able to resolve the issue by refreshing the Blocks HTML output cache.

Comment: Can you post the code in question? Is this a CMS page/block ?

Comment: @sr_magento `<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/banners/everyday-health-banner.jpg"}}" alt="Today's Top Supplements Below Wholesale Pricing" width="1920" height="580"  />` This is in the CMS static block.

Answer (score 2):

Beyond setting Magento in the backend to use `SSL` for your Unsecure base, I recommend using a 3rd party tool or website such as [Why no padlock?](https://www.whynopadlock.com/) that can help detect the non `SSL` elements of your website.

In my experience some modules that aren't very well written are hard codded to do `http://`.

Other areas could be `CSS`, a manually inserted link on your site that was written as `http://`.

`CMS` Blocks and Pages can also be responsible and should be looked at to ensure that they aren't offending.

Use the tool I provided to see where the issue is and correct as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, sr_magento! I know exactly where all of the links are, I'm just unsure of why they aren't secure. All of the image links are generated in my CMS static blocks in the backend using {{media url="image"}}. I've used this on many previous sites without any issues with secure links, but on this site I'm having issues.